# Lua module created with SWIG and MinGW, cause the interpreter to crash on exit

Tags: c++, lua, cmake, mingw, swig

I have the following files:

**hello.h**

```
#ifndef HELLO_H
#define HELLO_H

class Hello {
    private:
        int _number;

    public:
        Hello(int number);
        void printHello(void) const;
};

#endif
```

**hello.cpp**

```
#include "hello.h"
#include <iostream>

Hello::Hello(int number)
    : _number(number) {
}

void Hello::printHello(void) const {
    std::cout << "Hello, " << this->_number << std::endl;
}
```

**hello.swg**

```
%module hello
%{
    #include "hello.h"
%}
%include "hello.h"
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
FIND_PACKAGE(Lua51)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${LUA_INCLUDE_DIR})
ADD_LIBRARY(
    "hello"
    SHARED
    "hello_wrap.cxx"
    "hello.cpp"
)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(hello "${LUA_LIBRARIES}")
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(hello PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
```

I generate hello_wrap.cxx using SWIG, then I create MinGW Makefiles through CMake, and build them. This results in hello.dll.

Opening the lua interpreter, I type:

```
hello=require('hello')
inst=hello.Hello(23)
inst:printHello()
```

Which, as expected prints out "Hello, 23" as I want it to, so the module loading seems to work correctly.

However, when I then do:

```
os.exit()
```

I get the following error:

```
"This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information."
```

Followed by lua.exe crashing. This also happens when I simply do:

```
hello=require('hello')
os.exit()
```

Does anybody have any ideas as to how I may be able to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The following is the output produced by depends.exe when running test.lua with the problem lines, through lua.exe

```
***************************| Module Dependency Tree |***************************
*                                                                              *
* Legend: F  Forwarded Module   ?  Missing Module        6  64-bit Module      *
*         D  Delay Load Module  !  Invalid Module                              *
*         *  Dynamic Module     E  Import/Export Mismatch or Load Failure      *
*                               ^  Duplicate Module                            *
*                                                                              *
********************************************************************************

[   ] LUA.EXE
     [   ] KERNEL32.DLL
          [   ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-RTLSUPPORT-L1-1-0.DLL
          [   ] NTDLL.DLL
          [   ] KERNELBASE.DLL
               [ ^ ] NTDLL.DLL
          [   ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTHREADS-L1-1-0.DLL
          [   ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-HEAP-L1-1-0.DLL
          [   ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-MEMORY-L1-1-0.DLL
          [   ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-HANDLE-L1-1-0.DLL
          [   ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYNCH-L1-1-0.DLL
          [   ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L1-1-0.DLL
          [   ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-IO-L1-1-0.DLL
          [   ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-THREADPOOL-L1-1-0.DLL
          [   ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L1-1-0.DLL
          [   ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-NAMEDPIPE-L1-1-0.DLL
          [   ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-MISC-L1-1-0.DLL
          [   ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L1-1-0.DLL
          [   ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-L1-1-0.DLL
          [   ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSENVIRONMENT-L1-1-0.DLL
          [   ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
          [   ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-DEBUG-L1-1-0.DLL
          [   ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-ERRORHANDLING-L1-1-0.DLL
          [   ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-FIBERS-L1-1-0.DLL
          [   ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-UTIL-L1-1-0.DLL
          [   ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROFILE-L1-1-0.DLL
          [   ] API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-BASE-L1-1-0.DLL
          [F^ ] NTDLL.DLL
     [   ] MSVCRT.DLL
          [ ^ ] KERNELBASE.DLL
          [ ^ ] NTDLL.DLL
          [   ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-CONSOLE-L1-1-0.DLL
          [   ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-DATETIME-L1-1-0.DLL
          [ ^ ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-DEBUG-L1-1-0.DLL
          [ ^ ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-ERRORHANDLING-L1-1-0.DLL
          [ ^ ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-FIBERS-L1-1-0.DLL
          [ ^ ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L1-1-0.DLL
          [ ^ ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-HANDLE-L1-1-0.DLL
          [ ^ ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-HEAP-L1-1-0.DLL
          [   ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-INTERLOCKED-L1-1-0.DLL
          [ ^ ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-L1-1-0.DLL
          [ ^ ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L1-1-0.DLL
          [ ^ ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-MEMORY-L1-1-0.DLL
          [ ^ ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-MISC-L1-1-0.DLL
          [ ^ ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-NAMEDPIPE-L1-1-0.DLL
          [ ^ ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSENVIRONMENT-L1-1-0.DLL
          [ ^ ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTHREADS-L1-1-0.DLL
          [ ^ ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROFILE-L1-1-0.DLL
          [ ^ ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
          [ ^ ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYNCH-L1-1-0.DLL
          [ ^ ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L1-1-0.DLL
          [ ^ ] API-MS-WIN-CORE-UTIL-L1-1-0.DLL
     [ ^ ] MSVCRT.DLL
     [   ] LUA52.DLL
          [ ^ ] KERNEL32.DLL
               [F^ ] NTDLL.DLL
          [ ^ ] MSVCRT.DLL
          [*  ] HELLO.DLL
               [ ^ ] KERNEL32.DLL
                    [F^ ] NTDLL.DLL
               [ ^ ] MSVCRT.DLL
               [   ] LIBGCC_S_DW2-1.DLL
                    [ ^ ] KERNEL32.DLL
                         [F^ ] NTDLL.DLL
                    [ ^ ] MSVCRT.DLL
                    [*^ ] LIBGCC_S_DW2-1.DLL
               [   ] LIBSTDC++-6.DLL
                    [ ^ ] KERNEL32.DLL
                         [F^ ] NTDLL.DLL
                    [ ^ ] MSVCRT.DLL
                    [ ^ ] MSVCRT.DLL
                    [ ^ ] LIBGCC_S_DW2-1.DLL
                    [*^ ] LIBGCC_S_DW2-1.DLL
               [*^ ] LIBGCC_S_DW2-1.DLL
[*  ] SNXHK.DLL
     [ ^ ] KERNEL32.DLL
          [F^ ] NTDLL.DLL
     [*^ ] KERNEL32.DLL
```

EDIT: Added The output from 'cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"' and the build

**cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"**

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.1
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Found Lua51: C:/Users/forgottenmaster/Dropbox/lua/lua-5.2.3/src/liblua.a
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/forgottenmaster/Dropbox/lua/modules/c++
```

**mingw32-make**

```
Scanning dependencies of target hello
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello_wrap.cxx.obj
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.cpp.obj
Linking CXX shared library hello.dll
[100%] Built target hello
```

Comment: Can you run this in debugger so you can trap?

Comment: What if you remove `os.exit()` and replace it with `Ctrl-Z`? Does it still crash if you exit the interpreter using that key combination?

Comment: I couldn't find a decent lua debugger, I tried LuaEdit to debug but that just crashed without anything meaningful too. Running the script from C++ using the lua API, through gdb gives the following error at the exit of the script **"Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x775ddfe4 in ntdll!RtlFreeHeap () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll"**. Also, the Ctrl+C combination quits the lua interpreter without error

Comment: If you run a test script without `os.exit()` does that segfault? I believe `os.exit` just calls abort or terminate underneath so any cleanup that needs to happen may not be done.

Comment: Note `Ctrl-C` isn't the same as `Ctrl-Z`. The former sends a interrupt signal to the application to break out while the second sends an `eof` character to the interpreter which exits it naturally.

Comment: Running a test script without `os.exit()` also crashes as it is cleaning up, as does entering `Ctrl-Z`

Comment: Which C runtime is `lua.exe` linked to? By default and without going to some lengths to change it, MinGW is going to link against `MSVCRT.DLL` and not any of the newer Visual C versions. Lua for Windows is (IIRC) linking against `MSVCR80.DLL`. Mixing C runtimes will cause eventual pain, often due to confusion caused by multiple memory allocators with pointers received from one version's `malloc()` passed to the other's `free()`. The best way to see what is going on is to use `DEPENDS.EXE` to find out what DLLs are really in use.

Comment: opening lua.exe in depends.exe shows it's linking to MSVCRT.DLL as it was also compiled using MinGW from source

Comment: @ForgottenMaster When you say "opening lua.exe in depends", you are also running the script which requires your module, right? And depends shows the module .dll and shows it is using the same msvcrt version the lua.exe?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't. I just have run "lua test.lua" through depends.exe and got a dependency tree, I have edited my post to include this. It does seem like hello.dll and lua.exe both use msvcrt.dll

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things to try:

1. Your cmake has `FIND_PACKAGE(Lua51)` which could cause hello.dll to be linked against Lua 5.1, whereas you are running Lua 5.2.
2. Run lua test.lua via visual studio. You can do that a couple ways, one of them is to run lua test.lua and make the script pause, waiting for input; while it is waiting for input you run the visual studio and attach to the lua process; then you press enter in the lua console so the script continues; you'll likely know where the fault occurs (post file/line#).
3. I doubt the issue is a system DLL, more likely the hello.DLL is being built with incompatible settings such as single threaded instead of multi. Check that the Lua that you link to is the one for mingw, built with same compiler settings.
   The most important info from make is what is the final command for building and linking. Check what the compile and build commands are when you make Lua (maybe set the verbose flag for make -- what you posted just shows the status messages that g++ is being run, not the command line parameters given to it showing the include paths, etc), and find how to get those with cmake.
4. In principle you should be able to copy the Lua makefile and replace the few lines that list lua51.lib etc with hello.lib and co.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I used FIND_PACKAGE(Lua51) as there isn't a script in the version of CMake I have that is FindLua52.cmake. However as you can see from the output that cmake gives, it seems to locate the 5.2 version of the library

Comment: Following the above steps (adding io.read() call to script, running script in lua.exe, attaching visual C++ to process) gives the following error **Unhandled exception at 0x77E2DFE4 (ntdll.dll) in lua.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x6241C41F.**, i'm guessing this is the RtlFreeHeap function that gdb was complaining about. I'm trying the steps at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833 to see if it comes up as a corrupted dll

Comment: Yeah, I compiled lua  using mingw32-make  which is the same command as I use to build hello.dll.  there is a difference though in that building lua.exe I use the makefile that comes with the source,  whereas in mine the makefile is generated by cmake,  so I'm not sure if they have different compiler settings. I could post  then both to see if anyone can see anything,  I'm not sure about makefile syntax  myself

Comment: Posting the makefiles would be too much code, most important is the final compile and link commands with command line arguments. I've edited post to list the multiple comments into an answer that would be more useful. If still no luck, I think we will have to close this question, it would be more suitable for a discussion forum, and AFAICT you don't yet have chat priviledges on SO (need at least 20 rep points).